# Regular expression to find repeating hex values in css files

Tags: css, regex, colors, hex

I have a large amount of CSS files that I've extracted the hex colour values from. What I'd like to do now is to strip out any duplicates not found by uniq. For example, I have:

```
#ccc
#cccccc
#eee
#eeeeee
```

What I'd like to do is to run a regular expression against the file to identify the #cccccc and #eeeeee (or any other similar) strings, remove the last three characters so I can then run uniq against them to remove the new duplicates.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also note that `#123` is `#112233`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match (make sure it's case insensitive):

```
#([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3\b
```

and replace it with:

```
#$1$2$3
```

For example in Perl written as:

```
s/#([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3\b/#$1$2$3/gi
```

Example input:

```
#ccc
#cccccc
#123
#112233
#123123
```

Output:

```
#ccc
#ccc
#123
#123
#123123
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! You absolutely don't have to, but is there any chance you could explain how that works. I can see you're using backreferences, but don't understand it past that.

Comment: @fstorr, `([\da-f])` captures the first hex digit, `\1` matches the same digit again. Repeated 3 times for each color channel. Finally replaced by single digits for each color channel.